# Javascript placement of code

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is a script I have for a google spreadsheet. It all works except the last two lines of code. I'm not sure where to put them to work. I know they are correct, just not in the right spot i guess??

```
 function doStuff() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var starting_row = 2; // starting row to scan for part# on column C

  // outer loop, loop over products sold
  for (var j=6;j<=16;j++) {
    var r = ss.getRange(j,2);
    // read inventory part number entered
    var partnum = r.getValue();
    if (!partnum) {
      continue; // attempt to skip over empty rows in the B6:B16 range
    }
    var partcount = parseInt(ss.getRange(j,1).getValue());
    if (isNaN(partcount) || partcount<=0) {
      // invalid quantity. skip.
      continue;
    }

//  Browser.msgBox("partnum = "+partnum);

    // get list of known part # from the spreadsheet
    var parts = ss.getRange(starting_row,3,9999,1).getValues();
    var found = false;
    for (var i=0,l=parts.length;i<l;++i) {
      if (parts[i]==partnum) {
        // we have found our part. grab inventory count cell.
        found = true;
        var count = ss.getRange(starting_row+i,1).getValue();
        if (count-partcount<0) {
          Browser.msgBox("Error: Inventory for part "+partnum+", is "+count);
        } else {
          // write back the count number for that part, decremented by 1.
          ss.getRange(starting_row+i,1).setValue(count-partcount);
//          Browser.msgBox("Inventory updated.");
        }
        break; // either way, we're done with that part.
      }
    }
    if (!found) {
      Browser.msgBox("Part# "+partnum+" not found.");

**//I'm not sure where to place these next two lines. Everything else works but them. The    code is correct just not the placement.        
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast("Hello", "world?", 3);  
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(6, 1, 10, 1).clear({contentsOnly:true});**  
    }
  }

}
```

​

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are they supposed to be in that `if` block? Could try placing them right above the last `}`

I'm not familiar with google spreadsheet so this is a complete guess on my part. Just didn't seem right to be in that `if` block...

from this:

```
        if (!found) {
            Browser.msgBox("Part# " + partnum + " not found.");
            SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast("Hello", "world?", 3);
            SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(6, 1, 10, 1).clear({
                contentsOnly: true
            });
        }
    }

}
```

to maybe this:

```
        if (!found) {
            Browser.msgBox("Part# " + partnum + " not found.");

        }
    }
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast("Hello", "world?", 3);
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(6, 1, 10, 1).clear({
        contentsOnly: true
    });
}
```